# Tufte-class with Oscola citation format

Tags: citing, footnotes, tufte, sidenotes, oscola

I'm working on a book using the Tufte book class.

This the MWE:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyphenat}%
\usepackage[style=oscola, autocite=footnote, backend=biber]{biblatex}%
\addbibresource{oscola.bib}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%
\begin{document}
\justifying
This,\autocite{alcatel} should be a side note and this\autocite{verkehrsorgani} should too.

\lipsum[1-2]

This is \textbackslash{textcite\{alcatel\}}: \textcite{alcatel}

\lipsum[3-4]

\textbackslash{textcite\{alcatel\}}: \textcite{alcatel}

\lipsum[5-6]

\textbackslash{textcite\{verkehrsorgani\}}: \cite{verkehrsorgani}

\lipsum[7-8]

This is \textbackslash{textcite[See][10]\{alcatel\}}: \cite[See][10]{alcatel}

\lipsum[9-10]

This is \textbackslash footnote\{This is a footnote\}: \footnote{This is a footnote}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

The oscola.bib content:

```
@jurisdiction{verkehrsorgani,
keywords = {eu},
title = {Georg Verkehrsorgani v Ferrovie
dello Stato},
userb = {Case COMP\slash 37.685},
number = {2004\slash 33\slash EC},
institution = {Commission},
year = {2004},
journaltitle = {OJ},
series = {L},
issue = {11},
pages = {17},
}

@jurisdiction{alcatel,
    keywords = {eu},
    title = {Alcatel/Telettra},
    userb = {IV/M.042},
    number = {91\slash 251\slash EEC},
    institution = {Commission},
    date = {1991},
    journaltitle = {OJ},
    series = {L},
    volume = {122},
    pages = {48},
}
```

I need the content of all footnotes, sidenotes, and citations per the Oscola citation format (https://ctan.org/pkg/oscola?lang=en). I feel the results are not as close as I wish so I want to know if it is possible to modify the .cls or .def files in order to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please a) add `oscola.bib` with the used entries so we can compile your example and b) be a little bit more specific: What do you want to change? You say the results are not as close as you wish. Close to what? In what way?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I added the content of the bib file. I would like the result as close as possible to the output of the oscola.tex template in https://ctan.org/pkg/oscola?lang=en.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to modify anything. Just call  tufte book with the `nobib` option and load the `oscola` style with biblatex:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=oscola]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{abc,
    author = {John Doe},
    year = {1970},
    title = {Article Title},
    journaltitle = {Journal Name},
    volume = {1},
    number = {2},
    pages = {13--17},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib} 

\begin{document}

    Test!\footcite{abc}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you want your document to look more like the [OSCOLA Manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/oscola) you need to change the font and set the text justified:

```
\documentclass[nobib,nofonts,twoside,justified]{tufte-book}%
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[style=oscola,
            autocite=footnote,
            indexing=cite,
            backend=biber,
            ecli=yes,
            babel=hyphen]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{oscola.bib}

\usepackage[splitindex,
            nonewpage]{imakeidx}

\usepackage[mono=false]{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{beramono}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}

\section{Not Kant}

    This \autocite{alcatel} should be a side note and this \autocite{verkehrsorgani} should too.

    This is \verb|\textcite{alcatel}|: \textcite{alcatel}

    \verb|\textcite{alcatel}|: \textcite{alcatel}

    \verb|\cite{verkehrsorgani}|: \cite{verkehrsorgani}

    This is \verb|\cite[See][10]{alcatel}|: \cite[See][10]{alcatel}

    This is \verb|\footnote{This is a footnote}|: \footnote{This is a footnote}

\section{Kant}

    \kant[1-2]

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]